# Image rotation with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation

I can't seem to do this in my website... All I could do was hide the elements! The following is the code [at this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2d9r073o).

#### JavaScript

```
$("#image").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        mouseover : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({animateTo:180})
        },
        mouseout : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
        }
     } 

});
```

#### HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">
```

## CSS

```
#image{
  margin:100px 100px;
}
```

What's up with that?

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: Hi, I copied all your code into your post. Note that if you view the JavaScript console - in Chrome press <key>CTRL+SHIFT+J</key> - you will see the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` - this means you have not initialised jQuery correctly. It seems that jQuery 1.7.1 is no longer supported, so please select another version from the left-hand side of JSFiddle. Note that you now get a different error...

Comment: Thanks, but i included some other versions in my <head> but with no avail... the given google example works for me in fiddle but not im my website ven when i copy it over to the site :/

Answer (score 0):

jQueryRotate is... well it's a jQuery Plugin - it means it will not work without jQuery library. It's included in jsfiddle example (on the left side), yet I guess it's not that obvious :) A plugin itself should work with new version of jQuery, but if not, please submit an issue to the author of the plugin so he can fix it.

In other word in HTML put a:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Before including jQueryRotate.js script and it should work. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

It works for me.  When I mouse over it, it rotates until the cursor is no longer under it, then it rotates back.

You would probably get a smoother effect by bind the handler to the enclosing box, which would not rotate.

Comment: The given google example works for me in fiddle but not im my website when i copy it over to the site :/

Comment: So what you are saying is, everything you have shown us is where you know the problem _isn't_.  Why not show us something about where the problem _is_?